# iTunes U plays previous video when trying to open reading material

Tags: itunes, macos, itunes-u

I'm having a strange problem with iTunes U (in iTunes). When I click on a non-video item in the lecture feed, it simply plays the last video.
The item I'm trying to view is clearly not a video, as indicated by the book-symbol:

[image]

But in this example, when I click *"Reading: The Rest of Swift"*, it simply plays *"9. Scroll View and Multithreading"*.

I'm using a mac running OSX Yosemite, so there shouldn't be any problems with that.
Why is this happening then?

Answer (score 1):

The solution seems to be to first download the item, and then it will open properly.